# Concatenating two string arrays throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

```
    String[] aArr = ...;
    String[] bArr = ...;

    List<String> images = Arrays.asList(aArr);
    images.addAll(Arrays.asList(bArr));
```

throws the following exception at addAll and also raises the same exception if you add the elements of the second list individually.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
09:06:57,156 ERROR [STDERR] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:
131)
09:06:57,156 ERROR [STDERR] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:
91)
```

How should I rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
images.addAll(Arrays.asList(aArr));
images.addAll(Arrays.asList(bArr));
```

Note that as per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), `Arrays.asList()` returns a *fixed-size* list.  So if you want to concatenate both arrays, you need to allocate your own variable-sized list to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.asList(aArr);
```

returns an immutable list (well, size wise anyway), because the list just refers to the initial array for when you call get(i). so create another one that isn't like this, such as

```
List<String> images = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(aArr));
```

Comment: No it doesn't - it returns a mutable fixed size list backed by the array passed in the asList call.